# How to open a .cmd file from a python script

Tags: python, python-3.x

I have a `.cmd` file and I want to open it from a python script. The `.cmd` file (a converter) does its job when I open it without any further interaction needed in the command window. This means I only have to open it from my script, and that's it.

I tried the following...

```
from subprocess import check_output

def convert():
    subprocess.Popen(['[path to the .cmd file]')
```

... but it only opens the cmd window for a fraction of a second, and the actual `.cmd` file I want to run is not executed. What do I have to change to open the `.cmd` file behind my path?

**UPDATE**

```
from subprocess import Popen, PIPE

def convert():
    process = Popen("cmd.exe", shell=False, universal_newlines=True, stdin=PIPE, stdout=PIPE, stderr=PIPE)
    commands = r"C:\\CONVERTER\MFD2MAT\\convert.cmd\n"
    out, err = process.communicate(commands)
```

Comment: You may need to add `pause` to the script or execute with `/k`

Comment: @Jaxi Can you give me an example?

Comment: see hadi's answer. That should be what you want.

Comment: `subprocess.check_output(["cmd", "/c", "absolute\\path\\to\\your\\script.cmd"])` should work fine. In fact, even just calling the file should work, I'd print the output to see what's going on.

Comment: @zwer I think your answer works. I added (') before and after the (") and now i don't have "access" "WinError5"

Comment: @Rainer - Don't add any additional quotes as that's what the `subprocess` module does for you - you're getting that error, most likely, due to it not recognizing `'cmd` (notice the apostrophe) as an executable.

Comment: @zwer I added them because it didn't work without them. Do I only have to change the path or something else?

Comment: What does it print when you do: `print(subprocess.check_output("C:\\CONVERTER\\MFD2MAT\\convert.cmd", stderr=subprocess.STDOUT, shell=True))` ?

Comment: @zwer I think i figured out what happens. The cmd file is executed correctly but the converter I use doesn't work with the anaconda-prompt (which I think is used here). The converter says that it couldnt find the file to convert. When i execute the cmd file with the window from windows it works. Is it possible to execute my cmd file with the windows-cmd window?

Comment: If that's the issue, you can execute the command in a sub-process of a sub-process as: `subprocess.call(["cmd", "/k", "start", "", "C:\\CONVERTER\\MFD2MAT\\convert.cmd"], stderr=subprocess.STDOUT)` but if it's failing due to the path you might just want to supply a `cwd` argument and be done with it, i.e.: `subprocess.call("convert.cmd", cwd="C:\\CONVERTER\\MFD2MAT", stderr=subprocess.STDOUT, shell=True)`

Comment: @zwer Thank you very much! The second one is working. The converter couldn't find the file I want to convert with the first one. But with the second one it works just like I wanted it to. Thank you!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

My cmd file doesn't work with the "Anaconda-Prompt"

**Solution (from @zwer)**
If that's the issue, you can execute the command in a sub-process of a sub-process as:

```
subprocess.call(["cmd", "/k", "start", "", "C:\\CONVERTER\\MFD2MAT\\convert.cmd"], stderr=subprocess.STDOUT)
```

but if it's failing due to the path you might just want to supply a cwd argument and be done with it, i.e.:

```
 subprocess.call("convert.cmd", cwd="C:\\CONVERTER\\MFD2MAT", stderr=subprocess.STDOUT, shell=True)
```

Answer (score 1):

I will try to re-iterate with explanation:

**First Method:**

```
from subprocess import Popen, PIPE 

process = Popen("cmd.exe", shell=False, universal_newlines=True, stdin=PIPE, stdout=PIPE, stderr=PIPE)


commands = "C:\\Users\\praktikant3\\TESTING.cmd\n" #you can use " " for 1 line of commands or '''  ''' for several lines
out, err = process.communicate(commands)
print(out)
```

While formulating your command, keep in mind that your command
in the form of a python string, therefore:

- Make sure to escape your front/backslashes in your path: C:\.. => C:\\..
- Add `\n` to the end of the string to signal a newline to execute your command.

In my code, you can only see the output if you use `print(out)`, however the cmd file runs regardless.

---

**Second Method:**

```
import sys
import os
def run_command(command):
    print("Running command: {}".format(command))
    os.system(command)

commands = "C:\\Users\\praktikant3\\TESTING.cmd"
run_command(commands)
```

This is neat if you are using only one line of commands, and you don't need the break line `\n`, `os.system` does that for you. Also `os.system` will display the output in your **IDE** without the need to print anything.

Comment: Do I have to put the path which works when i manually execute the cmd file with the command window in between the (") symbols?

Comment: yes, unless the .cmd file is in the same current working directory as your python script. But when I use subprocess I tend to always give the path to my files regardless just to be sure.

Comment: This gives me the following error message: SyntaxError: (unicode error) 'unicodeescape' codec can't decode bytes in position 2-3: truncated \UXXXXXXXX escape

Comment: @Rainer before your cmd path string put r, so for example `r'cmd.exe'`

Comment: did you remember to escape your path front slashes ? Z.B:
C:\Users\praktikant3\ would become C:\\Users\\praktikant3\\

Comment: @Jaxi The r before the path removed the error. But the .cmd file doesn't open.

Comment: @HadiFarah I got the path by pulling the .cmd file inside of the command window. After that i copied the path which the command window showed but without the (") in the beginning and end and pasted it in between the (") of your exampe

Comment: add `\n` at the end of the command string: `commands = "call C:\\Users\\praktikant3\\TESTING.cmd\n"`

Call is not really necessary I was just messing around. This works on my end after testing it.

Comment: @HadiFarah I can't get it to work properly. I updated my current code in the question above. Maybe you could check it. It doesn't execute the .cmd file.

Comment: remove the r, it stopped working when I added r before my string

Comment: I have edited my answer to be clearer, let me know if it helps and use the same format don't add anything. And maybe one method is better than the other you can try both.

Comment: @HadiFarah Now i get an error from the subprocess.py: line 1113, in _communicate stdout = stdout[0] Index out of range

Comment: Thank you for your help @HadiFarah. In the end the solution from "zwer" did the job. Maybe because the converter I use is a bit picky.